# Why does addClass() work before start animation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, addclass

I use `queue()`. But I cannot get to my div turned red **only after** the animation ends.

How to do it correctly?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HrT6u/

HTML:

```
<div class="ext_div">
    <div>
        <span>A</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$("div.ext_div div").queue(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({opacity: "1", right: "400px"},
                      {duration : 1200, 
                       step : function() {
                                $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
                                $(this).addClass("animation_end");
                              }
                       }).dequeue();
     });
```

Comment: Do you even know what the `step()` callback does, or did you just guess it was some sort of callback function for when the animation was complete ?

Comment: Here -> http://jsfiddle.net/HrT6u/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change "step" by "complete" like this:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("div.ext_div div").queue(
        function() {
          $(this).animate({opacity: "1", right: "400px"},{duration : 1200, complete : function() {
                $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
                $(this).addClass("animation_end");
                                    }
}
                           ).dequeue();
                     });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.ext_div div").animate({opacity: "1", right: "400px"}, 1200, function() {
     $(this).css("overflow", "visible").addClass("animation_end");
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HrT6u/3/)